# jquery Hover - set initial opacity value on mouse out

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseevent, opacity

I have a canvas full of circles with a given random opacity. I want to had an hover function to animate the opacity to 0.5, but when the user moves the mouse away, mouseOut, I want to revert to the previous opacity of the element. The problem is that with the current function it's that all items revert to one single opacity value and not the previous respective value.

```
$( "circle" ).hover(
    function() {
        var initOpacity = $(this).attr('opacity');
        $(this).animate({"opacity": '0.5'}, 200);
    }, function() {
        var initOpacity = $(this).attr('opacity');
        $(this).animate({"opacity": initOpacity}, 200);
    }
);
```

Thank you

Comment: In second var initOpacity = $(this).attr('opacity');, you ge the current opacity, so you just animate to same opacity. So you should set the initial opacity outside the ().hover and use it.

Comment: @bksi: makes sense, but how can i target the current hover circle?

Comment: Your selector appears to be missing a period before circle assuming you're targeting a class on those div's

Comment: `opacity` is not an element attribute so `css()` is used instead of `attr()` to get the style attribute's CSS opacity property

Comment: Well example: $(document).ready(function() { var initOpacity = ... }); Then use initOpacity whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use css3, there is an attribute that you can use called hover `p:hover` and it will do all that for you. You can just set the opacity within the css itself

So you would have something like this:

```
p{background-color: red; opacity: 100%; transition: opacity 1s; } 
p:hover{ opacity: 50%;}
```

not sure if you have to set the color in the latter, it might inherit from the other one.

and sorry, missed the transition part.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a data attribute on each element and then there is no need to create a lot of additional event handlers for each hover.

```js
$(".circle").on({
mouseenter: function () {

    // Get opacity
    var  originalOpacity = $(this).css('opacity');
    
    // Store value
    $(this).data('originalOpacity', originalOpacity);
   
    // Fade out
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 200);
},
mouseleave: function () {
    
    // Get opacity
    var targetOpacity = $(this).data('originalOpacity');
    
    // Fade in
    $(this).animate({'opacity': targetOpacity}, 200);
}
});
```

```css
.circle {
     border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="circle" style="opacity: 0.7;" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <img class="circle" style="opacity: 0.4;" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        <img class="circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
            <img class="circle" style="opacity: 0.1;" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
```